# Add page numbers to the bottom of Process Shipments grid

Tags: c#, acumatica

I'd like to add page numbers to the bottom of the grid for the Process Shipments page.  Nayan from Acumatica had given us the following customization code:

```
 <ActionBar PagerVisible="Bottom">
   <PagerSettings Mode="Numeric" LinksCount="5" />
 </ActionBar>

 Set Grid's Skin ID to 'PrimaryInquire'
```

Both of these actions have been completed, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Page numbers add a significant performance overhead; it might actually not even be possible in this case given the way the list of shipments is generated.

Comment: Process Shipments screen has grid with AdjustPageSize="Auto". Set to None and see.  And yes page numbering does come with performance overhead as mention @Gabriel