# PagerSetting at the bottom of a grid does not display correct

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way to fix the vertical layout of the PagerSettings when displayed at the bottom of a grid?

UPDATE: I am working on build 19.110.0013

I am trying to add numbers to the bottom of a grid using the PagerSettings tag described in the post [Add page numbers to the bottom of Process Shipments grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37886240/594017).  When I set the PagerVisible to bottom the numbers display vertical, but if I set the PagerVisible to top the numbers are properly displayed as horizontal.

```
    <ActionBar PagerVisible="Bottom" DefaultAction="cmdItemDetails">
        <PagerSettings Mode="Numeric" LinksCount="5" />
    </ActionBar>
```

[image: PagerVisible Top]
[image: PagerVisible Bottom]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not reproduce that behavior in Acumatica version 19.106.0020 so I manually tweaked the CSS in order to reproduce that glitch.

Setting 'display: block' CSS property on GridPagerLink CSS class reproduces the same rendering.

[image]

In file '\App_Themes\Default\00_Controls.css' it is set as 'display: inline-block;'.
Inline option will make them stack horizontally so I don't have this glitch on my side.

Which exact Acumatica version are you running?

Use browser HTML inspect element feature to inspect the GridPagerLink.

Does it look like the default style below?

```
.GridPagerLink {
  display: inline-block;
  color: RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  height: 18px;
  border: solid 1px transparent;
}
```

Comment: I'm running 19.110 and the display was set to inline-block, but setting it to inline fixed the issue. Here are how the different display settings looked. 
 https://i.imgur.com/F71AcaP.png

Comment: I have updated my customization project to put in a custom 00_Control.css with change to the GridPagerLink CSS class.  If there isn't a better fix I'll just continue to upgrade the css file on each build upgrade.

Comment: Maybe the deployment was an update and it kept the style of an older version. Deploying a new Acumatica version shouldn't have that behavior.